# "Delete Backup" Option is not found in AWS Console in us-east-2 region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created on-Demand Backup for a DynamoDB  table(xyz) which is available in 'us-east-2' region. Unable to delete the backup from AWS Console. Please find the below attached file. we can't see the 'delete backup' button on AWS Console

[image: Delete backup not found]

Comment: Try refreshing the page and cleaning cache etc. Also do you see "Delete Backup" button when you navigate to all backups from left hand side navigation menu?

Comment: @Asdfg Tried with cleaning the cache still same issue. "Delet Backup" button is not visible in menu

Comment: Well, you are SOL. May want to open a ticket with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see what region you were working on. I was able to reproduce the scenario you described. Indeed, `Delete Backup` button is missing in UI. I believe this is AWS bug. Meanwhile, you can use CLI to delete the backup.

```
aws dynamodb delete-backup --region us-east-2 --backup-arn <<Backup_ARN>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the AWS has added the "delete backup" option for the region 'us-east-2'.